# If nodejs is Server side scripting language then how it is used in ReactJs or any other Front end language

Tags: node.js, reactjs, angular, vue.js, npm

If Node is server side scripting language then how it used in creating front end application like `npx create-react-app` or `npx create-nuxt-app`?

Comment: Those commands aren't run in the user's browser...

Answer (score 1):

When working on React JS or any other frontend framework, they usually come with tools like create-react-app(For React App) or create-next-app(For Next js app). These tools run on Node JS to help your development process.

Like in create-react-app, it makes a local server and serves your react app on localhost:3000. It also enables you to hot reload your app to quickly see the changes when you make changes to files in project.

When you make the release build of your react app. That no longer needs Node JS but it can be simply served from any web server.

TLDR: It helps to run development tools like create-react-app for easier and efficient development process.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Nodejs is not a programming language. It is an open-source, cross-platform, back-end JavaScript runtime "environment" that runs on the V8 engine and executes JavaScript code outside a web browser.

Now Come to your Question, why we use Nodejs is front-end Library or framework such as Reactjs or Angular because  Node.js provides customizability, flexibility, and a large library of packages to help create feature-rich full-stack applications.

**But in Case if you don't want to use Nodejs environment in Reactjs it's also Possible like:-**

app.js

```
var reactElement = React.createElement('h1', { className: 'header' },
'This is React');
ReactDOM.render(reactElement, document.getElementById('react-application'));
```

index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge, chrome=1" />
    <title>Snapterest</title>
 
     <script src=" /react-0.14.8.min.js"></script>
 <script src=" /react-dom-0.14.8.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="react-application">
     dsf
    </div>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

React js is a client-side library, if you write the entire code in pure Js (no jsx etc) you would not need node.js.
However for code management, react applications are divided or structed into multiple files, which needs node.js modules or lib processing to compile, combine, package, and generate a final client-side js script that can run on the browser.